# How to find no of paragraphs in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

consider that I  have a string say `sample` which is

```
"ApacheBench (ab) is a benchmarking tool that can load test servers by sending an arbitrary number of concurrent requests. It was designed for testing Apache installations.

cURL is a command line tool to send and receive data using various protocols like  HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, LDAP etc. It comes by default with most of the Linux distributions. 

Wrk is a tool that is similar to traditional Apache Benchmark. Configuration and execution are through a command line tool. It has very few but powerful settings, only the essential to generate HTTP load."
```

There are 3 paragraphs in the above string.How can I get the number of paragraphs using python ?

Comment: Have you tried counting newline characters?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch04s09.html) article

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: Pointing the OP there is certainly overkill. Besides that I hope you have notice that the article is from Python 2.1 era (~20 years old) - and that for, a text file for which one would want an arbitrary separator, a generator could do the job in about ~6 lines of code.

Comment: If your paragraphs are ended by `\n[white spaces]\n`, then just create a regex that will look for that marker, and count how many of them are in your text.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have double '\n' as paragraph separators. In this case, the number of paragraphs is:

```
text.count('\n\n') + 1
```

Comment: What if the line ending is CRLF? Or mixed?

Comment: @BartvanNierop: convert all `\r\n` to `\n` before doing anything else.

Comment: This will possibly yield unexpected results if the data includes spans of three or more blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your paragraph ends with a single line break or double line break, you can split the entire text by '\n' and then skip counting any lines with empty text (means empty new lines).

for example,

```
lines = text.split('\n')
count = 0
if not line.strip() == '':
    count += 1
```